# How to avoid logging expected exceptions that are correctly converted to status codes by Api-Platform?

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, api-platform.com

In some of routes for our Api-Platform project, exceptions  are `throw`n for some common error conditions.

E.g. while calling `POST /orders`, `NewOrderHandler` can throw either of this two if appropriate:

- `NotEnoughStock`
- `NotEnoughCredit`

All these exceptions belong to a `DomainException` hierarchy.

These exceptions are [correctly converted](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/errors/) to status code `400` on the response by using the `exception_to_status` configuration, and the response includes the appropriate error message. So far so good.

```
exception_to_status:
    App\Order\NotEnoughStock: !php/const Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
    App\Order\NotEnoughCredit: !php/const Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
```

The only problem is that the exception is still logged as a `CRITICAL` error, being treated as an "uncaught exception". This gets logged even in production.

I would have expected that by being converted to a correct status code (e.g. `!== 500`) these exceptions would be treated as "handled", and thus would not pollute the logs.

Throwing exceptions from the handler is convenient, because it helps deal with transactionality and automatically generates the appropriate error response message. It works for web and console.

Shouldn't these transactions be treated as handled? Is it necessary to create another exception listener to deal with this? And if creating an exception listener, how to do it so it doesn't interfere with Api-Platform error normalization?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a simple answer: handling an exception is not catching an exception.

Even if you convert your exception to a 400 error, your exception is still uncaught... that's why symfony logs it and this is done [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php#L108).

If you don't want to log any `DomainException`, just override the `logException()` method in order to skip logging if it's an instance of DomainException.

Here is an exemple:

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorListener;

class ExceptionListener extends ErrorListener
{
    protected function logException(\Exception $exception, string $message): void
    {
        if ($exception instanceof DomainException) {
            return;
        }

        parent::logException($exception, $message);
    }
}
```

Finally you need to tell Symfony to use this class instead of the Symfony one. Since there is no class parameter for the `exception_listener` service definition I recommend to use a compiler pass in order to replace the class.

```
namespace App;

use App\EventListener\ExceptionListener;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class OverrideServiceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('exception_listener');
        $definition->setClass(ExceptionListener::class);
    }
}
```

See [Bundle override](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#services-configuration) for more details.

Alternatively, just [decorate](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html) the `exception_listener` service with your own and no compiler pass is needed:

```yaml
App\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
        decorates: 'exception_listener'
```

Comment: If you don't want to log any DomainException, just override the logException method in order to skip logging if it's an instance of DomainException.

Comment: Do you mind adding to the answer how would you override `logException()` method? I now realize my folly and that it's easy to accomplish, but that's the answer I was looking for. I can also edit the answer and add it myself, but I'd end up performing a rather radical edit on the answer and I'm reluctant to do it without your explicit consent. That would a useful answer, bounty-worthy. :)

Comment: I edited my answer but feel free to improve it ! ;)

Comment: For some reason that I do not understand, the option of decoration does not work, the option of replacing the class, yes, but with decoration, no, I get an error that `$controller` argument is not defined, then looking at how the service is configured in particular, I put the argument controller `arg('$controller',param('kernel.error_controller'))`, but although it no longer gives any error, the new defined class is not executed.

Answer (score 3):

I tested it on a dummy application and I got:

> Apr 11 21:36:11 |CRITI| REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception App\Exception\DomainException: "This is no more logged" at D:\www\campagne\src\DataPersister\StationDataPersister.php line 53
>   Apr 11 23:36:12 |WARN | SERVER POST (400) /api/stations

You could implement your own log activation strategy:

This code is based on the [HttpCode activation strategy](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Monolog/Handler/FingersCrossed/HttpCodeActivationStrategy.php)

```php
namespace App\Log

use App\Exception\DomainException;
use Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossed\ErrorLevelActivationStrategy;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;

/**
 * Activation strategy for logs
 */
class LogActivationStrategy extends ErrorLevelActivationStrategy
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('error');
    }

    public function isHandlerActivated(array $record): bool
    {
        $isActivated = parent::isHandlerActivated($record);
        if ($isActivated && isset($record['context']['exception'])) {
            $exception = $record['context']['exception'];

            // This is a domain exception, I don't log it
            return !$exception instanceof DomainException;

            // OR if code could be different from 400
            if ($exception instanceof DomainException) {
                // This is a domain exception 
                // You log it when status code is different from 400.
                return 400 !== $exception->getStatusCode();
            }
        }

        return $isActivated;
    }
}
```

We also need to tell Monolog to use our ActivationStrategy

```yaml
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: info
            handler: nested
            activation_strategy: App\Log\LogActivationStrategy 
        nested:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: info
       console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]
```

Now my log contains only :

> Apr 11 23:41:07 |WARN | SERVER POST (400) /api/stations

Like @yivi, I'm not in love of my solution, because each time application will try to log something, you loose time in this function... And this method do not change the log, it removes it.

Comment: If by the end of the week nothing betters arrive, no qualms in awarding you the bounty. In the meantime, have an upvote! This is helpful.

Comment: I didn't see that you have answered you own question. I saw another problem with this solution. When there is a domain exception, all logs from this request does not appears, like the info "matched route".

Comment: This is a good answer, but I believe that the other answer offers a simpler, cleaner approach. I'm sure you'll agree. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While in Monolog, when using the `fingers_crossed` log handler, will [let you exclude from logging requests that respond with certain statuses](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/monolog_exclude_http_codes.html), it will only do so if the exception is an instance of `HttpException`:

I got around this by implementing a subscriber to convert the exception into an `BadRequestHttpException`.

```
final class DomainToHttpExceptionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): iterable
    {
        return [ KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => 'convertException'];
    }

    public function convertException(ExceptionEvent $event): void
    {
        $exception = $event->getThrowable();

        if ($exception instanceof DomainException) {
            $event->setThrowable(
                new BadRequestHttpException(
                    $exception->getMessage(),
                    $exception
                )
            );

        }
    }
}
```

This coupled with this monolog configuration does the trick:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        fingers:
              type: fingers_crossed
              action_level: warning
              excluded_http_codes:
                - 404
                - 400
```

I got this from [this answer](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/2339#issuecomment-445778443) on a GitHub issue. It works, but I'm not in love the solution. Hopefully some other answer will come to improve on this.

Comment: Leaving my original answer up only for historical purposes, but the two alternatives offered are better than this one.